# Trouble updating to 19.04

Tags: boot, updates, 19.04, cleanup

I have been trying to update to 19.04 (from 18.10) today. When I run "sudo do-release-upgrade", it aborts after calculating disk space changes with this error:

"The upgrade has aborted. The upgrade needs a total of 6,057 M free 
space on disk '/'. Please free at least an additional 2,552 M of disk 
space on '/'. Empty your trash and remove temporary packages of 
former installations using 'sudo apt-get clean'."

I have tried emptying trash and running "sudo apt-get clean", but it isn't sufficient.

Next, I ran df -h to see where I don't have enough memory- 
[here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUpV9.png)

I think the applicable line is:

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sda4        29G   25G  3.3G  89% /

As the "mounted on" matches with the error message and 3.3G roughly matches the amount of free space suggested in the error (1/1000*(6057-2552)). I have combed through other forums and found similar issues, all of which suggested carefully deleting old kernels. I tried that: running uname -r gave me '4.18.0-17-generic'. I listed all of the kernels with "dpkg --list 'linux-image-*'" (don't have the output as I closed the terminal and restarted since then), deleted all but the current version and one previous (I think), and restarted. On running the command again, I 
[get this output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWdzX.png)

I have what appear to be four valid entries (I'm admittedly not sure how all this works, and reluctant to delete anything else without advice at the risk of breaking something important), and a lot of linux image entries with Version = none. I am not sure if they still need to be removed somehow or what else I can do to clear up space for the update.

Any advice on whether or not I need to do more to remove old kernels, or other ways to clear space for the update would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. It looks like you've installed quite a few snaps & thus used all your space; so I suspect you may need to enlarge your partition (25gb is the suggested size, but the more programs/apps you install the more space is needed).   `df` is disk-free, and `du` is disk-used roughly, I'd suggest `du -hs /snap` and you'll see how much disk space you've filled with snaps; and I suspect why you need to enlarge partition, or you could remove some of those snaps, do-release-upgrade then re-install the snaps. Snaps [can] use more space than deb installs

Comment: This worked! I actually had multiple versions of snaps installed (didn't understand that when I first ran df -h), so removing the duplicates freed up enough space for the update

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt autoremove`

Will remove any old packages that were installed as a dependency of something else but no longer needed.  For example, if you install pkg1, and it pulls in another package named, let's say, dep1.  Then at a later date you uninstall pkg1, but for whatever reason dep1 is still installed.  If nothing else has identified dep1 as being something it needs, that means dep1 is just hanging out taking up space until you `sudo apt autoremove` it.  The command also removes old kernels that are no longer being used.  Don't worry, in my experience, it will always leave you one prior kernel version available as a fallback in case an upgrade to a new one goes awry.  I've never had an issue with autoremove breaking things because apt remembers which applications you manually installed and which ones were simply installed as a dependency of something else.

`sudo apt autoclean`

Will delete any downloaded package files that are no longer needed; i.e., the debs that were downloaded to install any software you installed from the repos.

Aside from that, you could always back up your files to an external drive and just do a clean install of 19.04, although that would mean setting up all your applications from scratch all over again.